# select and group , access the variables of select count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Ive tried a million ways and I cant figure it out,

how can I access the quantitymy and createddate (thats is in the model) of the following method, from view?

```
def self.groupit
  group("hour(created_at)").select("count(*) as quantitymy, hour(created_at) as createddate")
end
```

Im sure Im doing it completely wrong, group thing doesnt work either, 
can someone please help?
Thanks :)

Update:
I have a User model, a Group model and a Post model.

User belongs to one Group, Posts belongs to User. Posts belong to Group through a User only.

Im trying to show all the Posts thats been posted in the Group, grouped by their time.
So it should be

```
Group 1: 1 post at 13:00, 5 posts at 14:00

Group 2: 17 posts at 12:00, 1 post at 13:00, 2 posts at 14:00
```

etc.

Ive displayed it through controller as:

```
 @groups = Group.all
```

and then looped through them in the view:

```
<% @groups.each do |g| %>
    <% if g.posts.exists? %>
         <tr>
             <td><b><%= g.name %></b>;
             <%= g.posts.count %> posts
             <% g.posts.each do |post| %>
                 <%= post.created_at.strftime("%H") %>:00;
          <% end %>
              </td>
       <% else %>
            <% end %>
      </tr>
 <% end %>
```

**UPDATE 2/ ANSWER:**

```
<% @groups.each do |g| %>
    <% if g.posts.exists? %>
         <tr>
             <td><b><%= g.name %></b>;
             <%= g.posts.count %> posts
             <% g.posts.group("hour(posts.created_at)").count("hour(posts.created_at)").each do |created_at, quantitymy| %>
        <%= created_at %>; <%= quantitymy %>
          <% end %>
              </td>
       <% else %>
            <% end %>
      </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: You can(?) be more clear on what are your models structure and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ive added more details :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
group("hour(created_at)").count("hour(created_at)")
```

That will give you an ordered hash where they keys are the hour(created_at) values and the values are the counts.

You can display it like this:

```
Group.group("hour(created_at)").count("hour(created_at)").each do |created_at, quantitymy|
   # ...
end
```

Comment: how can I access that hash ? is it through loop in loop like i have?

Comment: Thank you :) But wouldnt that give me only access to when groups were created? I need posts rather then groups.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a super genius :) :) :)